# What does it mean counts plot in self organizing maps

Tags: r, plot, som, self-organizing-maps

I'm using the `som` function from kohonen package and I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/self-organising-maps-for-customer-segmentation-using-r/) as a guide.

```
som_model <- som(t(data_train_matrix), 
             grid=som_grid, 
             rlen=1, 
             alpha=c(0.05,0.01), 
             keep.data = TRUE,
             n.hood= "circular")
plot(som_model, type="count")
```

I have a data of 31×1400 but when I'm trying to read the counts plot, it doesn't match the same quantity of samples (31). The plot I got gives me around 100 samples.

this is an example of my data

```
structure(c(-8691, 96233, 94318, 19206, 139453, 135652, 47782, 
56190, -63139, 161452, 83268, 194879, -4112, 193153, -55742, 
168244, -26043, 171304, 67181, -52147, -45487, 77098, 79648, 
123380, -52991, 113980, -35812, 161776, -26874, 125046, 89662, 
94537, 68053, 59601, 87972, 8844, 82108, 85343, 145252, 130751, 
66224, 32792, 101576, 174156, 37090, 102740, 101521, 154264, 
28431, 81740, 113085, 104153, 6385, 95860, 67247, 58344, 106147, 
225375, -714, 212145, 51164, 24108, 33896, 128937, 182192, 5715, 
94954, 198818, 127890, 272457, -45888, 96562, 15617, 22385, 102185, 
154694, 93797, 55638, 118959, 184010, 6310, 54728, 141369, 209807, 
140799, 100809, 93704, 198260, 264015, 271577, 90354, 125713, 
112490, 103888, 186512, 178664, 30646, 100788, 194517, 197307, 
-3709, 111675, 175022, 186898, 242656, 107932, 269935, 110129, 
38492, 88179, 35392, 81003, 118482, 124713, 124830, 78896, 79962, 
154348, 181855, 8146, 90599, 115869, 58740, 119922, 12046, 216180, 
24770, 329719, 96091, 239658, 119638, 96020, 120758, 144941, 
170427, 26691, 112377, 246679, 170131, 314849, 97399, 194975, 
60680, 287463, 85241, 145845, 31902, 93297, 305020, 261229, 176675, 
146127, 306958, 62111, 101310, 113621, 208697, 73762, 354256, 
104883, 202739, 108740, 287507, 106152, 532421, 115689, 643646, 
143442, 1026203, 130904, 1951723, 83570, 5818682, 289423, 5864851, 
49296, 2369016, 184566, 1184562, 188584, 635480, 88563, 577216, 
144760, 454805, 139133, 510350, 40305, 366688, 55486, 258099, 
74080, 281519, 162968, 218759, 334500, 353090, 263008, 210560, 
445832, 378725, 497266, 298151, 469138, 248365, 381608, 219821, 
393548, 116469, 396907, 320685, 429351, 164311, 397822, 270935, 
565860, 245619, 435443, 214331, 417268, 268967, 459714, 419833, 
348551, 314194, 480522, 183062, 274876, 295398, 470877, 350616, 
425871, 642579, 670075, 395643, 679445, 333423, 524843, 207011, 
488471, 426073, 263541, 328925, 485258, 419273, 493798, 325854, 
505041, 317356, 394418, 254990, 432610, 254212, 459642, 311613, 
429672, 340076, 478631, 393919, 415449, 335445, 499644, 310914, 
479802, 229937, 317058, 321625, 349939, 410056, 450019, 389055, 
544372, 382828, 465619, 441888, 522416, 321660, 562040, 390768, 
427916, 356081, 477152, 481436, 609419, 589189, 710624, 1167121, 
1884282, 687543, 949401, 613100, 834546, 425695, 613319, 444637, 
624192, 684646, 771698, 726366, 813694, 616384, 756803, 483736, 
707427, 517319, 761253, 617534, 785160, 765434, 892135, 1057392, 
1144724, 902210, 1114782, 1027470, 1488406, 1794285, 3202191, 
1680875, 2378078, 1384652, 1942915, 1940959, 2753094, 8178326, 
9296747, 17334234, 18341903, 4077766, 4757832, 12437987, 13770176, 
5388983, 6043089, 3557519, 4344363, 3462297, 4193800, 3002130, 
3751664, 2889390, 3596128, 2990671, 4052441, 4551441, 7645868, 
6055792, 8720274, 11204851, 14342229, 13297134, 17421005, 16032135, 
22046214, 33034409, 41895354, 134659124, 309713419, 54318759, 
138429326, 21521670, 32507615, 31364480, 51975213, 41972208, 
70888295, 96423383, 193962950, 127239777, 183865572, 184485432, 
362581277, 266284997, 372142920, 254797938, 379524966, 168531540, 
217593817, 109955151, 132909067, 45946711, 52766776, 39059161, 
46851181, 36854510, 44138904, 42208748, 51775529, 30842738, 38044295, 
34739365, 62307643, 35222394, 263589982, 19288663, 53574604, 
22473059, 32180156, 15377680, 39229960, 14883020, 37024731, 26775128, 
38438456, 31174328, 37159679, 20374102, 24638170, 18843009, 23709900, 
16290335, 22019997, 13866224, 21410739, 13409806, 19807146, 12580394, 
19423477, 12605523, 20175243, 11286325, 15895629, 12624149, 20150895, 
15564663, 23173356, 13344234, 19144941, 16147475, 25059434, 16165655, 
22543911, 17719126, 26056352, 25241362, 33870246, 20346030, 25373366, 
27599769, 34874263, 19750731, 25488861, 17456089, 26803417, 21655991, 
29032569, 18525780, 28589676, 28986493, 54330313, 30702160, 62741684, 
36217696, 66746224, 37179427, 70384105, 32845869, 54067819, 40466477, 
60334993, 47169915, 71194010, 64983410, 94329526, 107713258, 
163970090, 205975485, 422860074, 727019292, 1894177881, 1536778649, 
2595541011, 1325315247, 1724342395, 623772789, 933707256, 520787992, 
763760597, 484959955, 762351348, 544836917, 814960223, 557751071, 
825802985, 484106551, 727516034, 320419472, 473245904, 215986703, 
319460038, 176355114, 258972369, 147044357, 203777597, 93349619, 
132506190, 89329707, 120091964, 56028958, 73913976, 39160835, 
57805430, 31597040, 45502763, 24996502, 38369765, 23164619, 34974560, 
23446564, 36260730, 24240365, 37462383, 24380634, 38464790, 23825674, 
38232189, 24261678, 40822263, 22545025, 37662136, 25969748, 41828554, 
25342961, 41373278, 28190579, 51622837, 40721443, 89715709, 33899480, 
63713905, 33879100, 82571628, 33194622, 63495601, 40899580, 83115054, 
52391035, 119897472, 43331860, 85516401, 40972806, 111409364, 
45229140, 86017237, 60769699, 114219430, 76387165, 153804973, 
100612861, 166584932, 119025540, 209322137, 125258469, 215257202, 
126370047, 181489720, 114200659, 190602759, 98391103, 165094932, 
82887335, 170246121, 62767360, 159226407, 53772778, 144576214, 
56504793, 178803162, 54720435, 176147058, 43853977, 160656487, 
40490358, 127145028, 46175432, 125716299, 47970998, 142990986, 
32686143, 96639106, 28256535, 113010719, 32245717, 109662077, 
49315728, 158277164, 39866932, 133740008, 29835677, 121148901, 
24484676, 101192015, 20524807, 79615303, 19472158, 67957180, 
17802439, 57347318, 17393829, 46409063, 21637835, 57425134, 24685542, 
64142491, 22664706, 52782681, 18106352, 45773357, 17952323, 35943518, 
22782703, 48608934, 29545983, 54107623, 20658150, 35173101, 19308973, 
30420232, 21648523, 33358523, 34925054, 57821290, 23749536, 52300713, 
22246131, 51411073, 29970764, 49549669, 28882978, 45160688, 23305717, 
42669741, 22496477, 42017707, 24123603, 37571652, 27087406, 46212322, 
31957832, 67751755, 31735687, 44207281, 31518232, 39656499, 44331797, 
66592574, 305051402, 236738335, 61016620, 351951034, 47694378, 
54296987, 57684704, 62552739, 72834978, 76647987, 77661681, 90054910, 
94027736, 105247183, 94705645, 118623817, 127635699, 168214213, 
125541816, 183982552, 158891836, 202074988, 154380584, 202356268, 
156180324, 227847605, 151802781, 210993781, 103866998, 140327139, 
91144468, 146060827, 78798545, 172226188, 94375043, 184702914, 
59593981, 111951306, 48128719, 67660907, 58181026, 63873729, 
58155047, 64229300, 59114829, 66547475, 51011422, 59659321, 40733341, 
48214428, 48326348, 55047638, 37896199, 42305785, 31219727, 37677791, 
36206563, 45170766, 30796703, 39213659, 29426202, 38564819, 31122601, 
41869397, 30150284, 39687478, 30251942, 41245534, 36266084, 50365634, 
42078213, 72001066, 38470907, 60095827, 45098881, 67795094, 32427023, 
43091370, 44211158, 69249130, 46198628, 72272292, 42080483, 59575435, 
67142635, 78404256, 91590826, 91367080, 81279600, 97189859, 159178282, 
145226665, 64489072, 69171662, 107042650, 117525720, 71536249, 
91016903, 55757027, 135642542, 41353460, 72293186, 68166846, 
222105000, 29394948, 73100483, 40777925, 101079557, 29585737, 
75349492, 25111702, 36658070, 20004139, 30107908, 17352754, 24086411, 
16352644, 23340098, 15867984, 21918125, 15447299, 22444804, 15101802, 
21772688, 28749939, 41991543, 18181681, 25302101, 15872482, 22007830, 
18623139, 27740895, 27122497, 38924843, 15959970, 23381320, 19605220, 
25139255, 20045670, 24677277, 17806558, 25316488, 17454866, 24929439, 
21039898, 27983508, 26828223, 37740624, 24913259, 41158419, 37691892, 
82078166, 39765574, 105437749, 39806713, 92607859, 36546145, 
79750166, 31341108, 76242765, 22884050, 66475659, 17116842, 41957883, 
12610875, 20866546, 11422645, 18295880, 11426134, 16997562, 10421891, 
16780423, 9952551, 15942561, 9597599, 16154386, 9345908, 15026048, 
8971600, 15287752, 8630352, 14028149, 8972152, 13734295, 9210456, 
15206966, 8586592, 14676163, 9113002, 15707156, 8724114, 14789908, 
9653042, 14574939, 10636733, 15123006, 10884812, 15665015, 16096044, 
31557043, 50665144, 69162457, 40125003, 67033492, 88178064, 117506119, 
48467438, 62147370, 48550396, 64970507, 28885550, 33953693, 14804984, 
21215748, 13263821, 19255188, 11543123, 16023682, 11155710, 13600438, 
13419212, 15819226, 11648329, 14025008, 15381219, 15881212, 18821434, 
23967947, 11387648, 12943318, 13650064, 17002021, 9341178, 11791878, 
7537499, 9877936, 7424723, 9225182, 7303770, 9539660, 7533521, 
9356114, 7445487, 9183369, 7723960, 10046696, 7069531, 8696718, 
6883109, 8408871, 6576015, 8175139, 6292912, 7827066, 6193985, 
7618591, 6092437, 7463851, 8007993, 9628431, 8214867, 9592375, 
5643731, 7108804, 7796140, 9073715, 7786279, 9218450, 5852014, 
7220848, 5531071, 6707757, 5325259, 7057039, 5144619, 6276074, 
4919355, 6112982, 4642040, 5895631, 4766331, 5898431, 4372028, 
5764096, 4425480, 5700040, 4791509, 5677859, 4351727, 6068910, 
4356586, 7292655, 6665298, 7799927, 6460052, 8712420, 8969410, 
13822499, 38495765, 43424278, 39621419, 44732021, 37841957, 45142206, 
34591715, 41608581, 36228112, 45347955, 35407558, 39870269, 25625081, 
28832164, 28159583, 30823422, 36269127, 36764400, 33333975, 33608379, 
33903467, 37356045, 49753141, 51095775, 36042304, 39506987, 40017888, 
40858778, 33928722, 31665538, 35496066, 34854597, 36648303, 34853318, 
40974424, 37693597, 37355103, 37254712, 40888929, 39220835, 46749102, 
45365054, 38692171, 38994526, 37071537, 38250689, 30771455, 30199810, 
30860932, 32031393, 26897069, 27840729, 33115398, 30062000, 37198082, 
34015339, 31362599, 34999206, 30190111, 29543583, 37835112, 33625379, 
36564345, 32805001, 33423060, 27516038, 27951644, 25433845, 28747171, 
29462452, 37615549, 32462563, 36596022, 35115114, 32025505, 33817468, 
28993647, 27627406, 32829876, 29419615, 28088898, 28000767, 25990459, 
25452615, 28452616, 22908176, 80282537, 44883045, 48061766, 31887840, 
26450990, 22957308, 21324193, 21018404, 21640103, 21695803, 20979613, 
20553114, 22796444, 21646388, 28102885, 25637043, 46302294, 30639089, 
78909133, 63895259, 924877222, 574298446, 61682541, 69381555, 
36784559, 44112668, 35770403, 39446356, 40450488, 46573911, 36409794, 
36249387, 32861168, 33681605, 27772410, 28078711, 22718664, 21390343, 
20514355, 20727964, 18684570, 18747393, 17864735, 18478176, 17042677, 
18099092, 21912916, 23904073, 23854075, 25437678, 28012160, 27610597, 
28921222, 27998643, 38371840, 38347990, 29883020, 31254336, 28944013, 
28106503, 22333477, 25509381, 37523067, 44624151, 51398284, 51326151, 
45237494, 48676641, 48884986, 36137123, 48455452, 50305940, 34113506, 
30096213, 47848045, 50180241, 29558817, 27433066, 23156895, 30452971, 
47913798, 81310397, 21173499, 36507223, 16705783, 44526670, 16915890, 
27976765, 39421477, 97994802, 18089480, 46748560, 19213895, 68914899, 
18327982, 25978185, 22752008, 26705144, 23232643, 37060652, 49410882, 
115207125, 35668038, 100482133, 32216745, 37102054, 26936190, 
37952923, 29880600, 59994902, 17154364, 36879989, 16187604, 18481243, 
36345076, 36791199, 34979093, 33833615, 35171628, 30291521, 18008813, 
18242520, 35924017, 34838177, 31498662, 30227506, 20756740, 18249859, 
15655526, 16252234, 13366295, 13884202, 12628160, 12998964, 36134899, 
31894894, 38682499, 42236948, 174659159, 161098060, 19201111, 
23133845, 15768300, 23803944, 15563058, 21015488, 12400951, 15170894, 
14463083, 15372174, 14145159, 13432976, 12508976, 14533641, 12603315, 
14752532, 29165535, 34701841, 34613004, 38382305, 12701108, 15299177, 
10542043, 11814855, 12720299, 14503320, 13262320, 16774322, 10999137, 
13968885, 12477166, 14675299, 11295054, 14260493, 8920837, 10540879, 
10821060, 12680480, 7308803, 8518389, 8708401, 9690657, 7360906, 
8333873, 7872593, 9331100, 14983661, 20052686, 7071602, 8167268, 
6752306, 7607500, 7300664, 8251348, 10283979, 10793896, 8633848, 
9200107, 7047555, 7782679, 7026706, 8085627, 7037919, 8680326, 
10692618, 11052656, 11815421, 14029510, 11321528, 11017049, 11148373, 
12237342, 10273471, 10712920, 10930483, 9380573, 10664164, 9876970, 
13067421, 9311465, 10683709, 8063691, 7772941, 5590061, 6222425, 
4846499, 5578634, 4242595, 5323003, 3907435, 4659877, 3810184, 
4686749, 3530004, 4106660, 3572372, 4192119, 3723871, 3911411, 
3725753, 3844458, 3938543, 4354640, 4345201, 5141553, 4971951, 
6759012, 6429379, 9578618, 8903225, 15996240, 14592373, 33416266, 
30327576, 87368361, 86730343, 116182636, 147896821, 50987865, 
66104255, 21879816, 25754860, 11882765, 13454804, 7726892, 8477395, 
5837996, 6149962, 4994890, 5079621, 4383296, 4387098, 4258400, 
4099896, 3964729, 3877924, 3337955, 3353870, 3603645, 3658213, 
3117322, 3254205, 3400425, 3487749, 3909460, 3903053, 4335854, 
4256376, 3558737, 3873069, 4237518, 4184615, 3879568, 4033895, 
4166573, 4595958, 4272930, 4539149, 4873247, 4683438, 6452743, 
7393386, 7265479, 12181806, 6763889, 7661375, 6971519, 6047856, 
6438627, 5386490, 5686910, 4848516, 5979046, 4854495, 5753200, 
4628045, 4952361, 4710863, 4565250, 4561258, 5486697, 5536561, 
4411443, 4537075, 4755574, 4706289, 5164482, 5076590, 5073376, 
7646303, 5311173, 10917625, 4101964, 5068857, 4337606, 5115597, 
4564387, 4668824, 4631901, 5467250, 4723013, 5798968, 5869221, 
7572800, 7765647, 10084591, 9597208, 11138673, 15000598, 15929891, 
15296224, 14624702, 18227523, 16894466, 16357620, 18928804, 23857201, 
26463772, 15077118, 19689309, 28562776, 38402739, 31931912, 44236189, 
37961974, 47425417, 47120253, 82298168, 117287497, 147415427, 
105762156, 132902413, 118794694, 148980103, 66277231, 66976258, 
47955638, 59812110, 42280110, 47196037, 37788708, 38700275, 24178459, 
22981247, 32673089, 32218495, 18744666, 16737281, 11989656, 10980265, 
8226540, 7846527, 5285698, 4718877, 3719617, 3816493, 3296615, 
3337248, 3349739, 3234481, 2725805, 3040272, 2784791, 2834818, 
2905428, 3418362, 3323803, 3547666, 3424843, 2993907, 2991925, 
3190753, 3698424, 3207622, 3041379, 3391014, 3548188, 3830123, 
2794684, 3171099, 2976888, 3409152, 2609357, 3076370, 3448181, 
3477913, 2395924, 3008964, 2935119, 2503567, 2747312, 3003776, 
2345180, 2887543, 2875523, 4047590, 3544112, 3356890, 2872637, 
2801455, 3385894, 2895361, 3228398, 2974132, 3224779, 2755368, 
2956570, 2778855, 2732627, 2535518, 2924457, 2712460, 2918495, 
2988522, 2940121, 2910417, 2799566, 2634529, 2843051, 2638672, 
2841214, 2506761, 2569948, 2651799, 2272136, 2412711, 2200321, 
2512456, 1782598, 2444849, 1586675, 2115228, 1662123, 2141720, 
1365500, 2291167, 1541416, 2250852, 1614926, 2097689, 1651982, 
2224546, 1476782, 2110319, 1613876, 2129865, 1684429, 2368080, 
1842319, 2484362, 1823977, 2267909, 1636541, 2482010, 1506425, 
2201026, 1704055, 2406874, 1754001, 2693560, 1958744, 2487501, 
1786765, 2647321, 1762151, 2506832, 2146423, 2569078, 1847711, 
2571620, 1971076, 2857411, 1825205, 2860939, 1694570, 2900597, 
1658465, 3454193, 2452289, 24374736, 2562823, 27360760, 1530087, 
4774473, 2406990, 18455112, 3438796, 43025599, 1892972, 5540505, 
1987491, 3729814, 1960989, 3339258, 1826160, 3126293, 1841758, 
3202876, 1975889, 3140266, 1784067, 2711450, 1759820, 2772621, 
1890299, 2798137, 1713928, 2681236, 1810850, 2695869, 1982948, 
2696095, 2046829, 2834138, 2032780, 2776086, 1883856, 2792566, 
2038178, 2667824, 2516633, 2671938, 2434678, 2777007, 2121305, 
3218425, 2393865, 4534850, 3026273, 3532661, 2508045, 3782342, 
2733001, 3722022, 2053139, 2918697, 2583343, 3507402, 3628020, 
3558825, 4760942, 4080084, 3503204, 3744204, 2564623, 3456410, 
3033733, 4347196, 4794716, 9519405, 39264539, 129542795, 31952500, 
90506566, 5440410, 10940205, 6986735, 42102411, 6807691, 18738039, 
5727356, 6646276, 6334260, 7106678, 27528625, 25385670, 12503497, 
10349194, 16741591, 15880339, 22913289, 23861758, 16395721, 20257989, 
27227267, 24764297, 10987688, 9991612, 14836286, 14178754, 15889351, 
15068307, 19056688, 19893617, 13550093, 74537094, 17046564, 64156917, 
16928452, 18709071, 7970680, 8679154, 21885172, 16677500, 11086138, 
10347864, 5777681, 6511858, 10702080, 8263870, 6414862, 5177301, 
7392801, 5522991, 7632363, 5521891, 4429442, 5141246, 4437962, 
4713124, 4682656, 5201962, 3357663, 4033730, 6347157, 4536040, 
5162888, 5858457, 4530111, 5514569, 3705917, 4395069, 4005062, 
4322744, 4137568, 4509432, 4568026, 4917769, 4246884, 4752821, 
4101506, 4794941, 4716765, 5100793, 5251493, 5487365, 5151850, 
5539515, 5329484, 5979635, 5693495, 6431739, 5551617, 6137586, 
6717681, 7579966, 8287942, 9944413, 7973593, 9539309, 6260445, 
6944790, 6639264, 7017903, 8661446, 8890185, 7452330, 7076329, 
8065504, 7758935, 12986285, 12510351, 14687851, 16016589, 10811421, 
10505975, 16936125, 16048723, 14235022, 14692536, 11515410, 10185673, 
12366240, 10845984, 11628100, 11152221, 12104536, 12209379, 11897270, 
11660802, 13841182, 10864520, 15370625, 10895724, 14362926, 9628075, 
16481124, 10886762, 21453723, 11848232, 27491072, 15788705, 43149552, 
33719668, 30596535, 27402730, 55715731, 36420718, 42660840, 40643469, 
26369805, 20993226, 17688010, 15372860, 13853568, 10276320, 14987013, 
10451967, 11915948, 8664789, 7948947, 6767177, 6562650, 5540239, 
6098262, 4965553, 8351472, 5203208, 7635639, 5066968, 9317502, 
5508798, 9179550, 5908849, 8243336, 5041237, 7386454, 5545817, 
8637649, 5760011, 8217680, 6006850, 21881677, 12726606, 45508424, 
36954717, 19157445, 23446346, 36113612, 23161366, 32250763, 30897388, 
21136706, 16206069, 30222602, 19291662, 16714054, 14372993, 15650123, 
10796328, 17412825, 15672118, 18807737, 17917709, 15503508, 10081708, 
11417608, 7923077, 10699799, 7749773, 14386948, 9261257, 56467667, 
33417304, 52890449, 48032293, 29062872, 23242018, 36501486, 25065587, 
23412523, 20826889, 19066199, 13908736, 10945865, 8582446, 12192383, 
6659470, 15113489, 6820906, 7424753, 5668608, 6933959, 5670777, 
6195668, 5768035, 10875709, 8193418, 7811554, 11609960, 7010878, 
6137633, 12463110, 12057172, 6545448, 7732166, 7126985, 6395963, 
14712971, 7478643, 16245271, 11206575, 8742793, 7826046, 10455331, 
6923893, 7973865, 7164603, 8153317, 7577606, 9840250, 9746034, 
14425877, 26246565, 54367548, 122538954, 26109680, 40166089, 
11137275, 12810374, 8641624, 9622083, 6658394, 6728764, 10523876, 
6634422, 6649192, 5785925, 6190257, 5878080, 10275940, 5990167, 
6047874, 19281908, 7720276, 89801987, 4375955, 12655641, 4618788, 
6776033, 6682859, 6004507, 4902971, 4857628, 5543398, 4571978, 
4709011, 4301051, 6197798, 7274294, 6679755, 7558111, 4087772, 
4809747, 3439387, 4404121, 3981186, 4155907, 4893781, 6083104, 
4977023, 6429334, 4893516, 5824296, 14311515, 20325943, 12896349, 
14917987, 5651188, 5331369, 4977180, 5787633, 4094555, 4877837, 
5385169, 4938339, 5704021, 5788051, 6524867, 5104170, 5125587, 
4480038, 4361553, 3857693, 5522122, 4442797, 6018572, 4736688, 
8359507, 5533513, 26298661, 16836405, 9494794, 12965025, 15970044, 
9261835, 12597059, 12515509, 11531908, 7522031, 25978385, 15344807, 
17410087, 16188748, 23840369, 15386360, 26054572, 18904748, 14266842, 
12893861, 6265884, 6181915, 10717623, 6973572, 11438989, 11864686, 
15902082, 10367689, 12820533, 10140250, 6767399, 5794777, 8072540, 
4987108, 4407985, 4579671, 3894191, 4071378, 3300006, 3446009, 
4659237, 3550968, 5111119, 3934388, 4529638, 3633981, 4401070, 
3305972, 3788658, 2815157, 4379994, 2563102, 3526197, 2799465, 
3371079, 2612031, 3395443, 2879536, 3167921, 3445117, 2728494, 
3387837, 2777852, 4002138, 3191039, 4896911, 3064223, 3744857, 
2882676, 2902579, 3192018, 3020582, 3389213, 3445934, 3991864, 
3692447, 7492313, 5699982, 19672453, 10839706, 265562556, 143875100, 
37315909, 46713627, 10699275, 8801800, 7451853, 7942848, 7310364, 
7842462, 6046960, 6140278, 6196309, 6506569, 5342634, 5545833, 
4889793, 5176057, 4779892, 5297344, 3807013, 4127983, 4305286, 
4807368, 3347352, 3570671, 2987449, 3389652, 2997169, 3208945, 
2894681, 3166850, 3108300, 3487693, 5614301, 6082539, 6426602, 
7359362, 6252190, 7040382, 3762828, 3877266, 3362161, 3465711, 
3401599, 3465280, 7227293, 6262747, 13237754, 12960688, 10409922, 
8986292, 22737209, 20786940, 10695245, 11105227, 20328453, 18559200, 
15286621, 16834838, 10300064, 10545877, 6270455, 6778050, 5363202, 
5383261, 5010046, 5296460, 3995311, 4354900, 2590026, 3069099, 
2618467, 2975881, 2437062, 2793579, 2326570, 2529690, 2170797, 
2789567, 2404439, 2458120, 2523752, 2489057, 2821219, 2815891, 
2334835, 2120994, 2075297, 2148385, 2051080, 2071283, 2018314, 
2112460, 2251169, 1845515, 1970813, 2018929, 1746810, 1834591, 
1841811, 1851426, 1970003, 1779241, 1941810, 1777824, 2109186, 
1774234, 2030660, 1765702, 1858116, 1778271, 1917918, 1785178, 
1828023, 1608377, 2865573, 2450871, 2389475, 1880194, 2051307, 
1727171, 2902959, 2174825, 2415768, 1962911, 2516672, 2145713, 
2006572, 1896725, 1994148, 1866227, 2054433, 1652913, 1645923, 
1772884, 2738784, 2259827, 1719877, 2384452, 1766685, 8205262, 
2198165, 69853478, 3131797, 8033983, 3482429, 3243942, 41344297, 
2362982, 11974176, 2233809, 2933079, 1896241, 1910444, 1533542, 
1626105, 1584269, 1696223, 1336963, 2446058, 1672874, 1844127, 
1491734, 1350359, 1308638, 1239937, 1088673, 1174309, 1058759, 
1568335, 1360706, 2408198, 2071746, 3011886, 2385974, 2004130, 
1624216, 2493848, 1818031, 2713902, 2849376, 1720433, 1543522, 
4498393, 3350395, 1777060, 2614621, 2080426, 1562895, 1902742, 
2330395, 1106693, 1284215, 1076838, 859232, 1088411, 809099, 
1660226, 1387403, 962019, 892591, 699096, 820620, 672778, 978114, 
762233, 588511, 685934, 703018, 1317503, 835060, 740301, 683674, 
596679, 840375, 790465, 868156, 654120, 577653, 701434, 896742, 
645360, 703156, 600585, 673209, 628230, 701949, 555575, 650786, 
554766, 507645, 581107, 639615, 562741, 698161, 666114, 749345, 
395458, 598941, 569225, 495801, 453205, 510450, 536268, 486821, 
341256, 577687, 512912, 594426, 785059, 845732, 4600127, 3115079, 
24186388, 21174502, 11207431, 11143093, 23510245, 21492747, 4962912, 
6832719, 1254627, 1343449, 6037434, 4468585, 32044645, 28029382, 
10078353, 10943453, 21016001, 18035347, 19715190, 20921866, 1665130, 
1850215, 685908, 666779, 500121, 529365, 543014, 453104, 723921, 
728066, 541418, 573654, 251205, 429521, 228239, 483925, 210967, 
549936, 403591, 426226, 321299, 274720, 403122, 442367, 366499, 
408785, 327629, 526714, 272867, 442841, 207223, 488989, 100714, 
442116, 311411, 338482, 634560, 231571, 864007, 663464, 414986, 
693304, 215624, 348521, 214632, 247313, 284767, 380655, 335655, 
302782, 237952, 234741, 119118, 290922, 56938, 228415, 145593, 
229541, 79279, 219851, 114883, 229190, 253440, 231830, 298345, 
343361, 659553, 583089, 5661473, 4763641, 42501347, 37465706, 
19046469, 19515752, 1678340, 1700477, 666387, 699187, 570783, 
576521, 418374, 314371, 330738, 240459, 280430, 291783, 270997, 
164393, 213340, 257488, 204183, 251663, 143228, 231753, 314947, 
284795, 462774, 463102, 655267, 557190, 992314, 626150, 281850, 
270902, 218983, 228705, 205245, 127646, 177902, 265351, 531852, 
483171, 504113, 533657, 178571, 399556, 429216, 341907, 339516, 
547767, 302428, 524955, 259506, 303736, 298121, 279209, 705637, 
839540, 1892941, 2688194, 832135, 1224368, 499247, 689864, 561686, 
411460, 401568, 376855, 389534, 381450, 324276, 270848, 253953, 
360355, 153729, 142692, 182576, 215206, 26731, 131634, 121065, 
279575, 8378, 354559, 3350890, 6042431, 731897, 1303240, 299307, 
269394, 188308, 372369, 93559, 394179, 165682, 569932, 282164, 
333632, 150821, 308888, 1788277, 3701803, 216357, 334917, 133974, 
148063, -19306, 217085, -40842, 186624, 99943, 272404, 161389, 
356429, 203508, 193395, 36872, 232185, 95510, 134201, 52049, 
190583, 180666, 270383, 351192, 559072, 99377, 176959, 80716, 
287869, 94236, 158161, 271578, 79586, 12655, 160936, 168816, 
284199, 173465, 189205, -46341, 50435, 129964, 191754, 83231, 
56092, 25193, 162338, 107541, -22639, 55217, 35787, 47909, 63362, 
53623, 98341, 84343, 83148, 68525, 281156, 200815, 325498, 7023, 
211971, 147348, 173311, 131772, 82241, 57698, 55677, 125820, 
75611, 141190, 206538, 121937, 132452, 109561, 285020, 288524, 
161788, 218752, 339620, 376737, 461421, 788267, 629020, 1200393, 
1242008, 2462325, 2464638, 3344975, 3831304, 2510363, 3074276, 
1173759, 1533410, 627920, 818287, 440831, 576747, 280345, 389708, 
339139, 383207, 146265, 193118, 199649, 245270, 192506, 139053, 
200213, 102594, 191376, 166123, 146673, 525440, 160612, 141108, 
214046, 163549, 81501, 89169, 229145, 149189, 127803, 224104, 
43046, 62199, 100512, 64995, 182381, 223371, 227468, 152893, 
188902, 161563, 271719, 180982, 195312, 132571, 185243, 204, 
190690, 42928, 260847, 86701, 266180, 101212, 432107, 84562, 
912283, 58893, 2052785, 149812, 2087275, 109099, 1221562, 212146, 
505035, 155971, 366796, 208734, 274636, 157009, 220756, 39843, 
123336, 140177, 51948, 85997, 186316, 159521, 73779, 142105, 
233432, 163863, 103808, 213311, 175274, 122588, 223116, -70881, 
51806, 95016, 199224, 129689, 16215, 14954, 83282, -58656, 64609, 
-37894, 75890, 81202, 25216, -57565, 4882, 223007, -104123, -6556, 
111613, 1972, 29788, 78473, 38631, 41930, 7173, -87043, 16431, 
42437, 40524, 75041, -47853, -24668, -83193, 97270, 93566, -64184, 
-53851, 72846, 81179, -88798, -85487, 93245, 99034, -53903, 48958, 
-11602, 61371, 76051, 161268, 73033, -120141, 17482, 71106, 871, 
55534, 7786, -36060, 49042, -9883, 40971, -3269, 12172, -17860, 
174429, 66996, 16702, 105242, -110576, 106180, -7294, -158111, 
55265, 29837, 57985, -38040, 60157, -15124, -94016, 17030, -61063, 
-92350, -56016, -31862, -2691, -34232, -151965, -80909, -85343, 
112232, 2900, -62024, -44420, 82929, 80607, 26812, -851, -116838, 
-100528, 60697, 112403, -144841, -22094, 1512, -21703, -62315, 
-173280, -5621, -5223, -138151, -18163, 107855, -46407, -831, 
140759, -5251, -101338, 15117, 22505, -159721, 38653, 75320, 
-18872, 49405, -50979, 37787, -84577, 91876, -56425, 82390, 46025, 
-27861, -35438, -10174, -26542, -95622, -115634, 83964, -128186, 
47685, -53810, 10099, 97387, 3935, 7213, -200517, 22792), .Dim = c(2L, 
1406L))
```

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what your problem is. It would help if you posted a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it more clear. Provide the minimal sample input to re-create the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have fewer items (samples) in the plot is that `kohonen` clusters items that are sufficiently similar.  Consider the data set wines from the package.  It has 13 variables for 177 wines, but the count plot shows 25 clusters.  It also shows how many wines are in each cluster by the color gradient.

```
library(kohonen)
data(wines)
kohmap <- xyf(scale(wines), classvec2classmat(wine.classes),
              grid = somgrid(5, 5, "hexagonal"), rlen=100)

plot(kohmap, type="counts", labels = wine.classes, col = wine.classes + 1, main = "count plot")
```

[image: 25 items after clustering 177]

Comment: thanks, yes I see your point but my gradient goes until 100 when I have 31 samples

Comment: But you have 1,400 variables (if I read your question correctly), so they may well "boil down" to 100 circles.  Can you provide your data with dput()?

Comment: yes I can but its too large, whats the appropriate way to do that, or simple added to the post?

Comment: Subset your data so that it is small, but reproduces your problem.  Once you have created the subset, enter dput(subset df) and then copy & paste the result into your question.  Click edit on the bottom and just write something like "Here is a sample of my data" and all the code you used.

Comment: I can't read your huge data.  Can't you provide a small subset, just enough to make your point?  I have taken too much time already.